# React.js: Loop through a state array to create multiple JSON request

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create this type of JSON request for multiple deletion of records

```
     [
        {
            "id" : "618D7054-339E-4B58-ADD2-45C0A4D2B915",
            "maker": "TESTMAKER",
            "status": "DELETED"
        },
        {
            "id" : "E698C439-EDB8-4652-9365-F64B3000B97E",
            "maker": "TESTMAKER",
            "status": "DELETED"
        }
     ]
```

The screen is composed of a datatable with checkboxes

I can now get the id of each record when checked with this code:

```
const selectRowBrstn = {
    mode: 'checkbox',
    clickToSelect: true,
    clickToEdit: false,
    onSelect: (row, isSelect, rowIndex, e) => {
      console.log("selectRowBrstn - onSelect row >>> " + row.id)
      setCheckedBrstnRecords([...checkedBrstnRecords, row.id]);
    },
    onSelectAll: (isSelect, rows, e) => {
      console.log("selectRowBrstn - onSelectAll rowIndex >>> " + rows)
    }
  };
```

With this, I'm putting the values in the state (array):

```
const [checkedBrstnRecords, setCheckedBrstnRecords] = useState([]);
```

Now, I have an array of ids in the state

The challenge now is for me to create multiple axios POST requests with different ids coming from the state

I have little idea on how to manipulate objects in the state

May I know what's the best approach for this?

Btw, here is the axios POST request:

```
deleteBrstnMaintenance(checkedBrstnRecords){
        return axios.post(`${API_URL_SAVE_BANK_MAINTENANCE}`,
        [
            {

            }
        ])
    }
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate over your state. It depends at which time you want to fire the requests and how many at a specific time.

What you are probably looking for is:

```js
useEffect(() => { // useEffect will be called if the variable in the provided array (in this case checkedBrstnRecords changes
  Object.keys(checkedBrstnRecords).forEach(el => { // iterate over the state
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      const currElem = checkedBrstnRecords[el]; // here is your element
      let res = await axios.post(API_URL_SAVE_BANK_MAINTENANCE);
    }, 70);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer); // clear timer
  })
}, [checkedBrstnRecords]);
```

Comment: forEach return value is `undefined`. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Can't I just fire 1 bulk load of post requests? Or there is really a need for timeout. Or wait for the response first